# media queries meta tag not working

Tags: responsive-design, media

I`am developing a responsive website,  when i view the site on mobile emulators and re-size the browser all responds perfect but when i look on actual mobile device the site does not resize

Here is my HTML head

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"></head>
```

here is my CSS

```
 @media handheld, screen and (max-width: 768px), screen and (max-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {{css styles}}
```

Any one help ??

Answer (score 1):

Remove the media query for handheld, these days mobiles fall under the screen area.

Check out http://mediaqueriestest.com to find out exactly what your current device is responsive to.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code in head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```